# grouping mysql results with joined table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

I'm making a simple table with list of articles, another table of users, and another of articles the users liked:

articles table:

```
id, userId, title, article, date
```

users table

```
id, name, email, last_login
```

likes table:

```
id, user_id, article_id, dateLiked
```

My current query:

```
SELECT 
articles.id as aid, articles.userId, articles.title, articles.article, 
likes.user_id as uLiked, likes.article_id as articleLiked 
FROM articles 
LEFT JOIN likes ON articles.id = likes.article_id
WHERE userId= "10"
```

So, I want to get all of a user's articles, then in the while loop, I check to see if the user signed in matches that row in likes, and show it active if it is. If it's not, it still shows as inactive.Same thing if they're viewing someone else's article. They should see all articles, but on the ones they linked should be active.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    if($row['uLiked'] == 30 && $currentArticleID = $row['articleLiked']){ $status = 'active'; } else { $status = 'inactive';  }

    echo '<div class="'.$status.'">'.$row['title'].'</div>';

}
```

The problem is that when the article gets liked, the post shows twice, but it is active both times. I tried grouping, but then when it groups, it shows the article once like I want, but nothing is active.

Hopefully I'm explaining it correctly, but I'm really stuck here. any ideas guys? I might be approaching this wrong..

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, your query as written won't work, because `user_id` is ambiguous in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use `group by`  then mysql group all rows in one row and for that mysql will only pick first row from grouped rows and other rows will be ignored.

So you have change some logic for that.

> use `GROUP_CONCAT` mysql method for that .

```
SELECT 
articles.id as aid, articles.userId, articles.title, articles.article, 
CONCAT(',',GROUP_CONCAT(likes.user_id),',') as uLiked, likes.article_id as articleLiked 
FROM articles 
LEFT JOIN likes ON articles.id = likes.article_id
WHERE userId= "10" group by {which every you want};
```

After that you will get data like `,10,30,15,`(`userid`) in `uLiked` parameter.

Now you can check by [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) method of string to identified login user.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    if(strpos($row['uLiked'], ',30,') !== false && $currentArticleID = $row['articleLiked']){ $status = 'active'; } else { $status = 'inactive';  }

    echo '<div class="'.$status.'">'.$row['title'].'</div>';

}
```

Comment: my man!!! that's exactly what I was trying to do... I changed it slightly by just  doing `GROUP_CONCAT(likes.user_id)` in the query, and `if (strpos($row['uLiked'], 30) !== false) {` but its exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: You have to put ,(comma) in starting and in ending otherwise in your condition 130 will also got satisfied which is wrong.